# Fixing bad file name or number on Ms Access, ico file

Tags: ms-access, office365

I am currently using Ms access on my laptop with Microsoft 365.

I would like to create an image button. I attempted image insert with both png and ico file types, however, once the image was selected it gives me a small box saying "bad file name or number."

I changed the name of the pictures into calculator and calculator.ico. They still didn't fill the trick.

I am struggling right now. Is there anyone who experience this or know way to shine me some lights fixing this? What should I do now? Please help, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Check that the image file format is compatible with Microsoft Access. Access supports several image formats, including BMP, GIF, JPG, and PNG. ICO format can also be used, but it requires a specific icon size (16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64 or 128x128 pixels).

Comment: I had no problem using a 24x24 bmp for a button. -- Could the file be locked or broken?